# benchmarking express.js login sessions

Tags: node.js, express, benchmarking, passport.js

I have a node.js backend which restful API endpoints. I can use `wrk` to benchmark http GET, POST, PUT requests. I can also use `pm2` module to track the cpu and memory usages.

But how do I emulate multiple login sessions? I want to benchmark logging sessions memory usages and find out with 1GB ram how many users can establish login sessions with the server. (I assume that when I see 100% memory usage on `pm2` and high latencies from wrk and that's the maximum # of session connections my server can take) And I on the right track?

p.s: I used `passport.js` to handle logins.

Comment: You could have a look at passport.js tests (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/tree/master/test), adapt them for your use case (maybe use https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), and run them in a loop (or use https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark). It would then be part of a test suite that you run less often (ie. not while developing), to make sure that there is no performance regression.

Comment: Can you share some of your test code so we can look at what kind of database/server is set up for your testing environment?  That will determine how we could look at benchmarking multiple sessions at once.

Comment: something like this. http://passportjs.org/docs all you do it `POST` to /login and you will be loggedin.  What passport does is: login and gives you a session cookie, in the future you just send this cookie and it will compare this cookie and fetch your user profile

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is generally called "Load Testing".

There are many tools that simulate many concurrent users and stress tests your site, such as, Tsung, ApacheBench, JMeter etc.

Here's a tutorial on how to setup JMeter so that you can load test your login page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGkrSFKcj10

When you run the test, JMeter is going to spawn more and more new users that will login (i.e. do a successful HTTP POST request) until the response time gets too large and if you have pm2 running while your test is running, you will be able to see how much RAM and processes is getting occupied at your peak concurrent user.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 seems to have difficulty installing jmeter, tried different sources.. is this a standard for testing logging in?

Comment: That's quite surprising. Are you installing via `apt-get`?

Comment: somehow I tried again and it installs this time... let me read into it this time.